# Varnish multi proxy via DNS config and regular expression

Tags: cache, varnish

I would like to set up a proxy "Varnish" as a bridge between public and private addresses. I thought I could use varnish and DNS servers to map private to public.

For example:
  http://service.domain - (Varnish) -> service-int.domain
  ...
  otherservice.domain - (Varnish) ->  otherservice-int.domain

I would like to have only to configure the DNS (service and service-int) for the N servers.

Do you think this is possible with varnish and regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

The DNS director may do what you want:

http://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/reference/vcl.html#the-dns-director

http://kristianlyng.wordpress.com/2010/08/02/varnish-backend-selection-through-dns/